# Measuring P and Q of house appliances

Tags: power, measurement

In order to obtain Power-Voltage characteristic of domestic loads (coffeemaker, microwave oven etc) I need to measure consumed active and reactive power at vooltage range U=[0.9-1.1]Un. Is there universl technique for such measurenemts? I'm a bit confused at the moment, because the loads should be live during the measurenemt, but where do I connect the mesurement circuit?

Comment: It really depends if you want to build your own measuring circuit or just use one off the shelf. Also what kind of accuracy do you need?

Answer (score 1):

Measuring AC power requires specialized equipment, unless the load is purely resistive.  Not only do you have to measure the voltage and current, but you must also measure the phase difference between the two.  Standard multimeters cannot do this.

[Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AC_power#Active.2C_reactive.2C_and_apparent_power) is a short introduction to AC power measurement.

I would recommend using the "Kill-A-Watt"-style product:

[image]

It is easy and inexpensive (less than $20 USD).  It can tell you how much real power is being used, the instantaneous voltage and current, what the power factor is, and so on.  It will even keep a running total for you so you can see average power usage over a long period of time.

Here's the Kill-A-Watt on [Amazon.com](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00009MDBU).  It is only good for 120VAC mains.

If you have 230VAC mains, the Prodigit 2000MU-UK [(pdf)](http://www.prodigit.com.tw/userfiles/admin/files/20140820_102156.pdf) looks like a decent option.

Comment: Such products can give wrong measurements if the load is a harmonic source. This is the same issue as in multimeters measuring "mean value" or "true rms". For harmonics the apparent, active and reactive powers do not keep the formula `S=sqrt(P^2+Q^2)` ([futher reading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_factor#Non-linear_loads))

Comment: I've used the Kill-A-Watt product and it measures true RMS voltages and current. As long as the harmonics are under the meter's sample frequency and don't have too much energy, the meter.